# How to add sharing to individual entries - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application where a user can create multiple entries.

I would like a user to be able to share an individual entry with another user.

I'm struggling to wrap my head around how to structure this.

The goal would be to allow a user to share an individual entry, and that entry be viewed in the other users entry feed. I don't want the "shared user" to be able to make changes, just view the shared entry.

I'm semi new to rails, and it's seems to be specific enough that I'm struggling to find a good answer by searching.

Let me know how else I can clarify the question.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a `user` can have many `entries` and can have also `shared_entries`.

#### database tables

```
entries       shared_contents       users
-id           -id                   -id
-content      -user_id              -username
-user_id      -entry_id
```

#### user.rb

```
has_many :entries
has_many :shared_contents
has_many :shared_entries, through: :shared_contents, source: :entry
```

#### entry.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :shared_contents
has_many :users_who_shared, through: :shared_contents, source: :user
```

#### shared_content.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :entry
```

This way you can share an entry like this:

```
entry = Entry.first
current_user.shared_entries << entry
```

Displaying it:

#### controller

```
@shareds = SharedContent.inclues(:entries, :users).order(created_at: :desc).limit(20)
```

#### view

```
@shareds.each do |shared|
  shared.entry.content
  shared.user.username # the user who shared
  shared.entry.user.username # the user who created the entry
```

This code is not tested, it may have errors.
Hope it will help, or at least give you an idea.

Comment: And for the editing part, you could use the pundit gem or the cancancan gem to protect entries from being editing by sheared users

Comment: thanks for this, it gave me a great head start. I had to make some tweaks like you said, but it was what I needed. thanks!

Comment: and I am planning on using cancan for that exact purpose.